# Why unordered linked lists? Is this a good balance of array/ll features for unordered structure?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list

I apologise if this is deemed off-topic, though I hope design of a data structure is sufficiently relevant to programming practice to be posted here.

I am learning C and C++, and having already covered arrays and allocation of memory, we began to look at linked lists. The lecturer stated their advantages as mainly being the ability to add/remove nodes without copying the entire structure - I can see that in order to add a node to an array, we need `existing_array_size + node_size` of *free* memory, despite the fact that we will then delete an entire `existing_array_size`. Even to delete an entry, we probably want to copy the whole structure out again.

With a linked list, we pay the price of execution time (in traversing potentially `n` nodes just to find and delete one) for the benefit of being more efficient with memory.

```
val of ll0
ptr to ll1
...
val of ll1
ptr to ll2
...
...
val of lln
null ptr
```

All well and good. However, what jumps to my mind (probably due to being completely new to it and not understanding properly, forgive me) is that we waste a lot of memory for `n+1` pointrs (I anticipate bickering about whether this is really a 'waste'.. it's *necessary for the method* but contains nothing of actual *value*).

The structure that seemed more obvious to me ***especially* for unordered lists** is as follows, take a `ptr to start`:

```
(start) ptr to end
val of 0
val of 1
...
val of n
(end) null ptr
```

So far this just seems like an array.. let's delete a value:

```
(start) ptr to end
val of 0
val of 1
...
(deleted0) val of m (= null)
...
val of n
(end) ptr to deleted0
```

Now insert a value `x`:

```
(start) ptr to end
val of 0
val of 1
...
val of m (= x)
...
val of n
(end) null ptr
```

An issue I now see only as I type it out, is what to do if we need to insert with no deletions, or even have to keep multiple pointers to deletions which would extend 'below' `end`, we cannot be allowed to overwrite some other item in memory if it is there.

Well in that instance, why not behave like a linked list, with this whole structure as a 'node'? Delete 2 items:

```
(start) ptr to end
val of 0
val of 1
...
val of m (= x)
...
(deleted0) val of a (= null)
...
(deleted1) val of b (= null)
...
val of n
(end) ptr to start1
...
...
(start1) ptr to end1
(end1) ptr to deleted0
ptr to deleted1
```

Okay, so suppose we now have some gaps due to deletion but nothing to insert. Maybe we want to spring clean a bit, it would be reasonably simple to 'shrink' by filling in the `start1` structure from `start2`, etc. With spaces in `start(0)` I suppose we would have no choice but to copy it out again.

Note here that `end` is not the *'end'*, but rather the *end of values*, to where we look for pointers to free space inside the structure.

- This has the same advantage over arrays as linked lists in saving us
  from making a copy on insert/delete.
- 'Free' space inside is not freed to other variables, but we can consider this a cost of the structure, comparable to (but far less in magnitude in all but the worst case* than linked lists)
- Insertion takes just as few instructions as in a linked list.
- Deletion takes one fewer than an ll.
- Size in memory greater than that of array, but lesser than a linked list*.
- Never copied entirely, maximum space required tends to `n` for large `n`, and is also proportional to `num_insertions/num_deletions`

*'worst case' is when every other element is deleted, and we essentially have a linked list with all the pointers at the end.

You may not have bothered to read this far before beginning to angrily type:

> **So what is my question?!**

Simple: What is wrong with this idea (unless of course, it/something very similar is used, in which case - what's it called?) - is it simply that it is always clear whether we want speed of insertion/deletion or to save usual space in memory, so this is redundant?

Thanks, and sorry for the long post, I felt it needed several examples to be clear.

Comment: A simple linked list is simple and straightforward.  The mechanics are repeatable with few decisions needed.  What you are describing seems overly complicated with many decision points and places for errors.

Comment: First of all, there is no language called "C/C++". The modern languages can be very different. On the other hand, your question does not really pertain to either language specifically (i.e. it could apply to Objective-C or other languages). In this case, the `algorithm` tag might be more appropriate than language tags.

Comment: @crashmstr I'm well aware. We've covered/are covering both. I'll remove tags if they're not relevant.

Comment: Note that one common set of nodes can be used as part of a messaging system between multiple threads, with each thread having it's own pointer to the first node of the list for that thread (or null if no pending messages). In the case of just two threads, and messages that always remain in fifo order for each thread, then a circular array could be used instead.

Comment: @RichardChambers Is strightforwardness a worthwhile aim? If I were suggesting this, I'd give you a handful of functions in order to accomplish insert/delete/etc. You only have to handle lack of simplicity once.

Comment: You can look at `deque` for a kind of `vector`-`list` hybrid.

Comment: @Simple: More a vector-hashtable hybrid (since its still supposed to be constant access complexity)

Answer (score 1):

First, bare in mind that we have different structures because we have different requirements. Your data structure may be quite suitable for *some* application, but it can certainly not be suitable as a generic replacement for linked-lists.

Here are three examples where the data structure fails to replace linked-lists:

#### Insertions in the middle

You focus on deletion, which is easy since you just mark the spot as deleted (which is by the way not always possible. Your data structure may not necessarily be storing pointers so that you could use NULL as a marker).

However, what would you do if the array is full, and you need to insert in the middle of it? You would then be forced to shift all the contents of the array (left or right to the nearest hole, or the end of the array if full), which is very costly.

#### Act as FIFO

Think of what happens to your structure if you use it as a queue. You would continuously insert in the end (i.e. enlarge the array with `realloc`) and mark as deleted from the beginning. Effectively, your array strictly grows in size, i.e. is doomed to fail.

#### Shared nodes

A good thing about linked-lists is that no matter how the actual links change, the data is persistent in the same memory location. Imagine someone has a reference to the data of a node in the list (i.e. a pointer to the data of the node). If you store those data in an array, then any shift of data (inevitable with insertion) would invalidate those pointers. However, with a linked list, the data address remains constant, no matter what and where you insert to or delete from the linked list (unless of course you delete that particular node!)

Comment: "Shared nodes": It might also be practical to have a node be part of multiple lists (or even more complex datastructures).

Comment: @PlasmaHH, sure. One nice example is an intermixed set and list, where lookup is `O(log(n))` and finding the next element is `O(1)` (not just amortized `O(1)`). Although this is often done with a threaded tree, this still has its uses.

Comment: Similar to the internals of most `std::unordered_*` container implementations.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - to clear some misunderstandings though: **Reqs)** I appreciate that - I did end by asking if the reason was that we would always favour one or the other. **Deletions)** I don't use null as a marker, I mark it by pointing to it at the end. **Insertions)** This is true - I sort of assumed it was unordered, though it would be no more expensive here than an array. **Shared nodes)** This is also true of my suggestion/question example, except when inserting in the middle which as I said I assumed wouldn't be done as unordered.

Comment: @OllieFord, assuming there would be no insertions in the middle is kind of a big assumption ;)

Comment: Not if, as stated, it is an unordered structure. It revolves around providing pointers to free space in the middle at the end - this is meaningless if it's ordered. An unordered structure has no requirement to insert into the middle, except if it is - like my aim - to reduce both memory and execution overhead from arrays/ll respectively, and done merely by definition of the structure.

Comment: @OllieFord, ok that makes things a bit different, but still doesn't address all the problems. The least of them is the FIFO problem. Your structure infinitely grows in size while the actual data is limited.

Comment: @Shahbaz FIFO represents an order. My structure wouldn't do what you describe (new would push to the end, anything popped would append a pointer yes, but then the next push would fill that spot and delete the pointer) - and as such wouldn't be useful for an ordered queue like this.

Comment: @OllieFord, right. Your structure is very specific to a special kind of problem and with particularly large data (to see the benefit of removing the pointers). On the other hand, finding the holes requires a linear search which is very bad on large data. One option would be to keep a linked-list of holes so you can find them fast, but then the number of holes should be small enough not to add more overhead than you saved by changing away from linked-lists in the first place.

Comment: In short, your structure (adding a linked-list to optimally find the holes) is excellent for large unordered data where the number of deletions is small. If you do have such an application, by all means use your data structure. However, to answer your question: _is it simply that it is always clear whether we want speed of insertion/deletion or to save usual space in memory, so this is redundant?_ of course it's never clear, but except in very special cases (large data, few deletions) a linked-list would be preferable to your data structure.

Comment: By the way, pay attention to the fact that if data is not extremely large, then some memory overhead is preferred over search time overhead, since memory is abundant. On the other hand, for huge data, you'd likely use a database which has much more complicated (and more efficient) data structures than what you have described. See for example [B+trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) that have reduced number of pointers and still support ordered data and fast look-up.

Comment: Thanks again for all the input, I find this kind of thing interesting even if I know little about it. Why does finding holes "require a linear search"? The first address of the structure contains a pointer to a pointer to a hole - that's not a search, just two accesses, always.

Comment: @OllieFord, I know you'd like to think of this structure as perfect since you came up with it yourself (although I'm sure a lot of people, myself included) have thought about something similar in the past, but try to look at it with criticism if you really want to know if it's good or not.

Comment: Try to see how this data structure behaves with many deletion/insertions. Would you have a lot of fragmentation? Ultimately, the best way to understand if your data structure is practically better or worse than others is to implement it and test it heavily and compare the tests with other data structures. Since you keep unordered lists, you can simply put it under test comparing with a standard linked-list implementation. You might think the extra pointer overhead is too much. Who knows, maybe it turns out it's not that much.

Comment: No no - not at all. I was sitting in the lecture and I thought "why not *this*", it's been on my mind since, and so I asked, purely to further my understanding. Please realise I'm not suggesting it's perfect (even good), or that anyone use it.

Comment: I will try to implement it and compare against linked lists and arrays with some actual data (of different sizes and operations) as you suggest. Thank you for your help.